# Uploading multiple images using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am trying to upload an array of images the user selects . They are `base64` encoded . I am getting a null response from the server . Here is my code below.

```
for (PHAsset *asset in assets) {

[manager requestImageForAsset:asset  targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:self.requestOptions resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {


   NSString *encodeStr = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];      

  [images addObject:encodeStr];

   }];
}
```

I am getting images from delegate using **QBImagePickerController** . I have a `NSMutableDictionary` as the body content for `NSMutableURLRequest` .

```
[uploadObject setValue:@"32" forKey:@"userid"];        
[uploadObject setValue:TFname.text forKey:@"Name"];        
[uploadObject setObject:images forKey:@"SelectedImages"];        


JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:uploadObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
```

Here is the `NSMutableURLRequest`

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:JSONData];
```

I am getting a server  response code as 500 and a null response from the server . I have tried both `NSURLSessionDataTask` and `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. 
Any help would do good !

Comment: can you show us format of your url?

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uploadURL];` , `uploadURL = @"www.xxx.com";` This is the url .

Comment: Image should be upload as multipart form data!! not as base64Encoded string!!

Comment: Have you set NSAppTransportSecurity??

Comment: Yes i did @VishalSonawane

Comment: How could that be done ? @KetanParmar

Comment: refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250475/post-multipart-form-data-with-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250475/post-multipart-form-data-with-objective-c)

Comment: can i send multiple images using the method referred above ?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631178/uploading-image-to-server-detail-explanation-for-beginner/38695956#38695956) ..It may help

Comment: Thanks @Gokul . But I don't seem to get this into my head. Is that multiple images are added to single instance of `NSMutableData` ?

Comment: Yes,multiple images are added to single `NSMutableData `.

Comment: Can you make it clear to me , I am appending image data to an instance of `NSMutableData` . This is set as the body content to `NSURLMutableRequest` . Now I'll have to add some 5 key-value pairs which i previous sent as a `NSMutableDictionary` converted as JSON object . Now my question is , how can i give this parameters object as well as images as a single `NSMutableData` object to the request ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to determine whether this code is correct or not without seeing the server-side code.  It looks like you're sending the following to the server:

```
{
  "userid" : "32",
  "Name": "someFilename",
  "SelectedImages": [
      "base64-encoded-data-of-first-image",
      "base64-encoded-data-of-second-image",
      ...
  ]
}
```

If your server understands how to parse a JSON request body and take fields with those names, then it should work just fine.  HOWEVER, it seems unlikely that the format is correct, as you're passing in multiple images with what appears to be single filename.

If you are using existing server code, you need to find out what format it expects the data to be in.  If you're writing your own server code, you should probably structure the data more like this:

```
{
  "userid" : "32",
  "SelectedImages": [
     {
        "name": "firstFilename",
        "data": "base64-encoded-data-of-first-image"
     },
     {
        "name": "secondFilename",
        "data": "base64-encoded-data-of-second-image"
     },
      ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me either . The server expects it to be sent the way i did .

Comment: Either way, the problem is either that you're not sending it in the form the server expects (e.g. are you sure it expects JSON?) or there's a bug on the server side.  Your client code is fine.

Comment: Correction: Your content type is probably wrong.  Try application/json.

Comment: I am getting a null response and status 200 again .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Found the issue sometime ago .

The problem was with the server side .